# Using System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.GetInstanceNames

Tags: vb.net, performancecounter

When I use System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.GetInstanceNames call, I always get 0 instances returned the first time.  If I actually query for a counter value first (using perfmon) and then call GetInstanceNames, it works fine.  Can someone provide some insight?  Do I need to get a counter value first (in code) and then use the GetInstanceNames?

Comment: Do I need to add more detail to my question to get a response?  Am I missing something obvious that everyone is staying away from my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  I added a call to System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.ReadCategory before trying GetInstances.  That seems to fixed the issue I was seeing.